# error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

Tags: git, github, ssl, devtools

When I installed ArchR using devtools, I got a error message below\

```
> devtools::install_github("GreenleafLab/ArchR", ref="master", repos = BiocManager::repositories())
```

Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

What is the problem? and how can I solve this?
Of course, the ca-certificates.crt is exist correct path (/etc/ssl/certs)

I also update ca-certificates by sudo apt install, reinstall and update.